# Javascript caching on iPad HTML5 fullscreen web application

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, caching

I'm having an problem where the iPad insists on loading an old copy of a .js file, instead of the current one. Strangely enough, this only happens when the page is in fullscreen mode, not when it's being run from the page.

- I'm not using any kind of cache manifest;
- When I open the page on Safari, it behaves as dictated by the latest version of the .js;
- When I open the page through the icon, it behaves as dictated by the old .js;
- Killing the running application, deleting the icon and then creating it again doesn't solve the problem; it's still using the old .js, even while in full screen.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

-- update --

This seems to be an [iOS 5 bug](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3385843?start=0&tstart=0).

-- Workaround (a.k.a. ugly hack) --

Simply add some fake http params to the script tag, so that the cache thinks it's entirely another JS:

```
<script src="js/pentaho-jqm-repository.js"></script>
```

Becomes:

```
<script src="js/pentaho-jqm-repository.js?fkn-ios-bug=1"></script>
```

Comment: I believe that if you view the page in privacy mode it will not be cached. Give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't test it because after adding the parameter as above and then removing it again, the cache problem stopped happening, just like that. Sporadic iOS bug, maybe?

Thanks for the tip, anyway; I'll try it next time the cache bug hits.

Comment: Just ran in the same problem on iOS 7.0.4. I didn't add a param though; the problem went away after restarting the iPad.

Comment: I noticed some other strange behavior, too. I added several new icon links while debugging, and each time I added one the previous one's name changed to the original icon link's name. I deleted all of the icon links before restarting the iPad, but half of them reappeared after the restart.

Comment: I ran into this problem with not refreshing .js files that were loaded in an iframe and only when in home screen mode. It helped me delete the browser history, too, not only the cache as one would expect. Working with iOS7 on ipad. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using the aforementioned workaround (adding a fake parameter to the URL) and then changing it back, strangely enough, the problem stopped happening. Of course, in a production environment, one wouldn't be able to do this, so I think I'll just start numbering the js versions so that the end user won't have this problem.